# Overlapping Div Element in GridView

Tags: html, css

I have gridview..and inside gridview i have put dropdown.. now whenevent user selects dropdown  the dropdown list doesn't and it overlaps the div element
as shown in below image.  i have applied Z-index in my CSS how can i solve it?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi can u say where is the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You just check where & how you are using the z-index because if you will give the maximum value of z-index into your drop-down list than it will not overlap the div element below the image.

or just show us your example code.....